# How should I set up a version of Linux so that it will use absolutely the smallest amount of RAM possible?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, memory, operating-systems, window-manager

I need to set up a bunch of virtual machines using virtualbox.  They are all going to be used for exactly one task, and nothing else.  I want to run as many as I possibly can at once, but have limited physical memory on my physical machine.   They are going to be running a python program, which uses OpenCV for image recognition, and Selenuim for automated web browsing.  I can't think of any reason why they need to have much of a desktop environment, although they DO need to be able to show gui applications in windows.  I have no need to use any 64 bit software.  I was thinking of using a 32 bit version of Debian with only OpenBox window manager, but I don't know if there is a lighter weight distribution, or lighter weight window manager out there.

Also, Once I figure out what version of Linux will require the least amount of memory to run smoothly, I will also need to know about what that amount of memory actually is, so that I know how to configure virtual box.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I know you talked about Virtualbox, and I don't know alot about it - but you may want to look at docker containers as an alternative solution - it seems to me its designed for what you are trying to do.

Comment: By "windows", I mean XWindows.  The GUI is needed in order to collect images via a screenshot utility during automated web browsing.  It is critical that the images look exactly as they would to a human viewing them on a screen, so the web page image download utility in Selenium will NOT work.

Comment: @davidgo - Docker runs using Linux. Even if you run Docker under Mac or Windows, it still uses a Virtual Machine and exposes the necessary networking interfaces.

Comment: @cricket_007 Virtualbox and Selenium also run under Linux, and there is every indication that the OP is looking for a Linux solution.

Comment: Perhaps start with a linux that is "light by default" - such as Gentoo or Arch. Gentoo encourages you to build the kernel, and only installs what you need.  And maybe use xvnc which is contains an x server and frame buffer, so may be lighter weight than a full x install.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is highly subjective and comes down to time vs money.

The linux version which will use the least amount of memory starts off being  one you compile from source, eradicating everything you don't need.  I suspect this is beyond what you are trying to do.

Similarly, you have not described what the GUI is needed for or how (the comment "show gui application in windows) is highly ambiguous in context. By Windows do you mean XWindows or Microsoft Windows ?   I note that you don't need any Window manager in order to run an application which outputs to a GUI - you can just use an XWindows server - but even that is negotiable - it is possible for the output to be pushed to another XWindows server - thus you may be able to run multiple apps but only a single server.  If you are looking for a minimal, off-the-shelf Window manager, Openbox, LXDE and XFE are all considered lightweight.

Older versions of Linux require a lot less memory, but this may not be practical.  When I started, HARD DRIVES were less then a GIG in size and the OS came on floppy disks.

Answer (score 0):

How about DSL, [**Damn Small Linux**](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/). The whole OS is 50MB.